# ¿Cómo encontrar las palabras de longitud menor o mayor que la media aritmetica de una cadena?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Primero convertí la cadena en una lista, sumé las longitudes de todas las palabras y lo dividí entre el total de palabras para así sacar la media aritmética.

```
st = "Yo estoy estudiando programacion"
lt = st.split()
x = 0
for i in lt:
    x += len(i)
    m_a = x/len(lt)

if len(i) < m_a:
    print("las palabras menores a la media: ", i)

elif len(i) > m_a:
    print("las palabras mayores a la media:", i)
```

Pero el programa me devuelve:

```
las palabras mayores a la media: programacion
```

Deberia salir también "estudiando".

Por favor podrían ayudarme.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que al terminar el ciclo `for` la variable `i` termina con el valor `programacion`

Por eso al realizar la comparación unicamente la estas realizando con la palabra `programación` y no estas comparando el resto de la palabras.

Lo que debes hacer es recorrer nuevamente la lista de palabras y compararlas contra la media, y las que cumplan las condiciones definidas agruparlas en una lista aparte.

```
st = "Yo estoy estudiando programacion"
lt = st.split()
x = 0
for i in lt:
    x += len(i)

m_a = x/len(lt) # No es necesario que este dentro del ciclo

menores = []
mayores = []

for i in lt:
    if len(i) < m_a:
        menores.append(i)
    elif len(i) >= m_a:
        mayores.append(i)

print("las palabras menores a la media: ", menores)
print("las palabras mayores o iguales a la media: ", mayores)
```

Otra forma más compacta de resolver este problema utilizando el modulo statistics y lista de comprensión:

```
import statistics as stats

frase = "Yo estoy estudiando programacion"
media = stats.mean([len(palabra) for palabra in frase.split()])
mayores = [palabra for palabra in frase.split() if len(palabra) >= media]
menores = [palabra for palabra in frase.split() if len(palabra) < media]
print("las palabras menores a la media: ", menores)
print("las palabras mayores o iguales a la media: ", mayores)
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias , funcionó muy bien..

Answer (score 4):

Creo que aquí se trata de "particionar" las palabras una vez que han sido ordenadas ("lower bound" y "upper bound") alrededor de la longitud media.

```
import bisect
st = "Yo estoy estudiando programacion"

# Genera 2 arrays ordenados, uno de longitudes y otro de palabras
ls, ts = zip(*sorted([(len(x), x) for x in st.split()]))

avlen = sum(ls) / len(ls)  # longitud media

bpoint = bisect.bisect_right(ls, avlen)  # punto de particion
print('mayores:', *ts[bpoint:])
print('menores:', *ts[:bpoint])
```

Podemos generar una lista de "tuples" de palabras y longitudes (tras el `split`), ordenarlas y separarlas en lista de palabras y lista de longitudes.

Como los elementos son correspondientes, particionamos la lista de longitudes con bisect y utilizamos el punto de partición en la lista de palabras.

Resultado

```
mayores: estudiando programacion
menores: Yo estoy
```

Nota:

- No queda claro en la pregunta que debería pasar con las palabras de longitud igual a la de la media, y si la media tiene que ser un "entero" o se puede considerar el valor fraccional. Con `bisect_right` dichas palabras quedarían como "menores" (lo que tiene sentido si la media no es directamente un entero). Si la media tuviera que ser un entero y tuvieran que considerarse como "mayores" entonces habría que aplicar `bisect_left`